# A working method to open a webpage in new window?

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch-2, new-window

I have been trying to write a code in sencha touch, which has a button and when i click on that , it should open a webpage as a pop-up in a new window .

1. Window.open()-I cannot use this method because it doesn't work fine
   in phones.Though I realise this is the easiest way to open a new
   browser window.
2. document.location.href=url - This method opens the URL in the same
   page , but I want it to be opened in a new window as pop-up.

Is there any other way to open a page in a new window when a user clicks a button, Below is my code

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Opening new page',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel", {
            fullscreen: false,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'click to open google',
                    ui: 'confirm',
                    handler: function() {
                        document.location.href=("http://www.google.com/");
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not use Ext.window ?

Comment: Can you pls gimme a good example of using Ext.window inside a button event?

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this code:**

```
handler: function() {
  var link = Ext.getDom('hidden_link');
  link.href = 'http://www.google.com'/;
  var clickevent = document.createEvent('Event');
  clickevent.initEvent('click', true, false);
  link.dispatchEvent(clickevent);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work ! nothing is displayed when i put this inside the handler function!

Comment: or you can try this code: <A HREF="http://www.google.com'/" TARGET="_blank">a new window</A>

Comment: <a href > creates a "link" , through which we can open an URL , But it should be opened on clicking a button in a new window instead of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how to do it in Ext.js, but I was basically thinking along the same lines as @bunlong-van.  Create a anchor tag that targets a new window, add it to the page, and then click it.

This is how it could be done in jQuery:

```
  $('button').bind('click',function(e){
      var $me = $(this);
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('<a />')
        .attr('href', $me.data('href'))
        .attr('target', '_blank')
        .css({display:'none'})
        .appendTo($('body'))
        .get(0).click();
  });
```

Full Sample: http://jsbin.com/adakur/edit

Answer (score 0):

Hey @coding you can that is a Overlay is a type pop-up, try this into handler event,

```
var overlay = new Ext.Panel({
    floating : true,
    modal : true,
    centered : true,
    width : 500,
    height : 500,
    styleHtmlContent : true,
    html: '<div><iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" src="http://www.sencha.com/products/touch">Your device does not support iframes.</iframe></div>',
}).show('pop', true)
```

**And please use your brain, I do not I can be doing your homework**. I hope this helps. :) Ciao[image]

Comment: It doesn't work @hekomobile! :(  . I still didn't find a better solution to this simple problem ! Hope I get one soon

Comment: Show me how do you doing. I don't know

Comment: {items:[{xtype: 'button',text: 'click to open',
                                    handler:function()
                                    {
                                       var overlay = new Ext.Panel({
                                        floating : true,modal:true,centered : true,width : 500,height : 500,styleHtmlContent : true,
html : 'http://google.com/',
                                                                                    items: [],
}).show('pop', true);
                                    }
                                         }]});}});

Comment: hey @codingactive I update my answer and please put your brain to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use window.open() in your handler as mentioned below:

```
handler: function() { 
    window.open("http://www.google.com/", "_blank"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a pop up window(a simple window) in your working page and make its visibility to false.. when you click on the button, change its visibility to true and give the focus to it..
also you can open anything in that popup window..

or you can use this jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() { tb_show(title, "testpage.aspx?id=" + url + "&TB_iframe=true&width=700&height=600", null); });
```

in this you can pass the parameters you want. this will open as a new popup window.

Comment: The first one( creating a popup window and set its visibility to false) will work. I am sure on that.. But i dont know whether the second idea will work.